# Resharper Line Comment not working (even from the menu)

Tags: resharper

Has anyone had this annoying problem? I can't seem to be able to comment lines with Resharper's Line Comment Feature. The hotkey does not work, even clicking from the menu does not work.

I've tried resetting VS keyboard shortcuts, setting IntelliJ/IDEA schemes and VS' schemes back and forth, saving Resharper's preferences. It does not work. Heck, I even tried resetting my pc. I'm clueless right now. Certainly I don't want to reinstall VS 2013 because of this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a bug from using Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Git Provider. Changing to "Git Source Control Provider" fixed it.